# ipad orientation portrait to display e message or trigger the Landscape

Tags: jquery, ipad, landscape, landscape-portrait

I'm trying to push the users to switch view with ipad. 
The correct view should be Landscape.

What's the best way?

a message? appending some html and hiding the portrait content?

**Jquery used**

```
  if (window.orientation === 0) {

               window.addEventListener('orientationchange', callback, false);

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

1. catch the `orientationchange` event on the `window`
2. use different style sheets depending on the orientation

e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="portrait.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:landscape)" href="landscape.css"> 

<script>
    window.addEventListener('orientationchange', callback, false);
</script>
```

Comment: thanks Alnitak do you know how to maybe push the user to switch?